# If for ideal I, radical R(I) = I, is I a prime ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

We know that for any prime P, the radical R(P)=P. However is the converse of this Statement true. That is, if we know that radical of an ideal I is itself, i.e. R(I)=I, is I prime? I presume it is not but couldn't come with a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this is not true. For a counterexample, consider the ideal $I = (xy) \subset k[x,y]$ for any field $k$.

Comment: Nice answer. I think you can generalize this by taking $R$ to be any UFD, and $I$ to be the principal ideal generated by any squarefree (nonunit) element (e.g., $R = \mathbb{Z}, I = 6\mathbb{Z}$). In general, $I$ is a radical ideal of $R$ if and only if $R/I$ is reduced, which is a fruitful way to produce examples.

Answer (score 0):

For $I$, $J$ ideals we have

$$R(I\cap J)\subset R(I)\cap R(J) \subset R(I J)$$
so
$$R(I\cap J)=R(I)\cap R(J)$$

Therefore, if $R(I)=I$, $R(J)=J$, then $R(I\cap J) = I\cap J$.

That should provide other examples of ideals with $R(I)=I$ (radical ideals), for instance finite intersections of prime ideals.

Other examples: since $R(R(I)) = R(I)$, then $R(I)$ is radical.

Note that if in the given ring every ideal is an intersection of primary ideals ( true for every notherian ring) then every primary ideal is an intersection of prime ideals.